# How to get Ajax to load/display data AND return a variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I currently have a piece of code

```
    $("#hlist").load("sg_ajaxCheckHymn.php",{hm: $("#textbox").val()});
```

that correctly runs a php file which does a database lookup and returns some nicely formatted data that is displayed in the Div called hlist.

The database lookup also collects another variable which is NOT to be displayed but which I want returned such that I can use it in a javascript variable later. (It's going to be the input to another Ajax query.)

Is there a way to do this in one Ajax call (Display some of the date and keep another bit for use in a variable) or do I need to do two separate calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your AJAX request to return a JSON response containing multiple information, such as something like:

Output of `sg_ajaxCheckHymn.php`:

```
{
    'db_data' : { ... },     <-- to be displayed
    'hidden_data' : { ... }  <-- to be handled in JS, ...
}
```

Then, after your AJAX succeeds, you can handle JSON output like (assuming you have jQuery, see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
$( ... ).ajax(
  ...
).then(function(data) {
  // Display DB results
  $('my_div').html(data['db_data']);

  // Handle other JSON data in the way you want
  console.log(data.hidden_data);
});
```

Then you can do what you want, having both DB results to be displayed after AJAX, AND some other (hidden) Data you want to handle in another way, and so in one unique ajax request.